# Discrete Convolution

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Does someone know the equation for the discrete convolution? I found [here](http://www.jhu.edu/signals/discreteconv/) that the formula is:

$$\{x*h\}[k]=\sum_{t=-\infty}^{+\infty}{x[t]\cdot h[k-t]}$$

But when using in Matlab/Octave the command below:

```
 conv(a,b)
```

With a = [1:3] and b = [5:8] I get that the answer is [5, 16, 34, 40, 37, 24]. But I can't find any initial value for "t" to get that result. Is the equation correct? What are the values for "t"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The values of $t$ for which the inputs are zero are ignored. Since $\mathbf{a}$ has length $3$, whenever $t<0$ or $t>2$, the value of $\mathbf{a}[t]$ is taken to be zero. The conv() function just returns the non-zero portion.

Comment: Potential typo: $a = [a:3]$?  Is this really what you meant?  Perhaps $a = [1:3]$?

Comment: @anorton Yes, as evidenced by $5$ being the first element in the output.

Comment: But isn't true that matlab/octave uses 1 as the initial index for the array? Anyway thanks! In that case, for example if I want to know what is {x*h}[3] then I would have ... + x[1]h[2] + x[2]h[1] + x[1]h[0] + ... = 6+10 = 16. And for {x*h}[4] = 34

Comment: Yes, matlab/octave uses 1 as the initial index rather than zero. It's arbitrary as long as you are consistent. It looks like you've got it figured out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When all else fails, [read the manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) `:)`

> Let `m = length(u)` and `n = length(v)`. Then `w` [the output of `conv(u,v)` is the vector of length `m+n-1` whose `k`th element is 
>   $$w(k)=\sum_j u(j)v(k-j+1)$$
>   The sum is over all the values of `j` which lead to legal subscripts for `u(j)` and `v(k+1-j)`, specifically `j = max(1,k+1-n) : min(k,m)`.

In your example, $m=3$ and $n=4$. With $k=2$ (for instance), the summation is over `j=1 : 2`
$$w(2) = u(1)v(2)+u(2)v(1)=1\cdot 6+2\cdot 5=16$$